# Can we use parallelism in analyzing partitions of a table?

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

It was taking hours to analyze the partitions. Are there any commands to parallelly analyze the partitions of a table?

Comment: Which commnad are you using: ANALYZE or DBMS_STATS?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `DBMS_STATS` to gather your statistics you've got a couple options.  If you're making explicit calls to `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` and `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_INDEX_STATS` you can use the `degree` parameter to set the degree of parallelism.  You can also set a default by using the various `SET_*_PREFS` routines in DBMS_STATS to set a default degree of parallelism, by object type or for the entire database (`SET_DATABASE_PREFS`).  For example

```
DBMS_STATS.SET_DATABASE_PREFS('DEGREE', '10');
```

will set a default of 10 for degree in subsequent calls to DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS.  Or you can just use the degree parameter to GATHER_TABLE_STATS, as in

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => 'A_SCHEMA',
                              tabname => 'A_TABLE',
                              degree  => 10);
```

If you're using `ANALYZE` to analyze your tables - well, you probably should change over to DBMS_STATS as ANALYZE has been obsolete since Oracle 9, if I recall correctly.  The `DBMS_STATS` package has lots of routines with lots of parameters but most parameters have reasonable defaults and so don't need to be specified.

You might try re-posting this question on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: hey @BobJarvis since you have over 3k rep, you can vote to close/migrate a question - juck click on close -> Offtopic -> dba.stackexchange.com - that'll migrate the questions & all answers to [dba.se] instead of OP having to repost.

Comment: @Sathya - in this case I decided not cast a close & migrate vote because the OP is a relatively new user and I didn't want to discourage him/her from posting or confuse him/her by having the question suddenly vanish.  YMMV.

Comment: alright, but once a question is migrated, there will be an auto-redirect to the migrated site. Just thought I'll let you know. Cheers